# grails command object and fields with prefixes

Tags: grails, prefix, command-objects

Im using grails 1.3.7 and here is the case...
Have a huge form with a few different **prefixes** for its fields (later used in data binding) and trying to validate thru a **command object**... however the lovely DOT used in prefixes is giving me a hard time and cannot get the names mapped properly in command object... any suggestion please?

in the form have fields like field like this one:

```
<input name="dealer.name" value="${dealer.name}" type="text">
```

and for command object:

```
class somethingCommand {
    String name
    Map dealer = [:]
    static constraints = {
        dealer validator: {
            val, obj ->
            obj.properties["name"] != ""
        }
    }
}
```

what if.... we look at it in another way and map the parameters before passing to command object... how should I pass my parameters to a command object without using grails magic?!?!?!

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could grab the "dealer" map in the controller via

```
def dealerMap = params["dealer"]
```

and then create a dealer command opject by hand and bind the map content to it.

```
def dealerCommand = new DealerCommand() 
bindData(dealerCommand , dealerMap)
```

you can then use the validation of the command object as normal

Comment: so here is the final implementation:
def docheck = { DealerformCommand zcmd ->
 def cmdParams = [:]
 cmdParams['zipCode'] = params["zipCode.name"]
 zcmd = new DealerformCommand()
 bindData(zcmd, cmdParams)

        zcmd.validate()
        if (zcmd.hasErrors()) {
   println "\nit is providing errors:>>>>>>>>>>>}"
            zcmd.errors.each {
                println it
            }
 } else {
  println "\nIt has passed the test"
 }
 render view:'someForm'
}

Answer (score 0):

Databinding properties with prefixes to command objects is supported:

For the command:

```
class DealerCommand {
    String name
    Map dealer = [:]
}
```

Properties named 'name', 'dealer', 'dealer.name' and 'dealer.dealer' will be bound correctly to the command object.

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#commandObjects